# Presto fails with type mismatch errors

Tags: presto

I have faced the following error and spend my a few days to figure out why Presto fails to read some specific tables. Just wanted to share solution who will face same error in the future.

**Problem stacktrace**

```java
org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.exec.DBCException: SQL Error [16777224]: Query failed (#20200212_074009_00007_z9eqz): The column event_timestamp is declared as type timestamp, but the Parquet file declares the column as type BINARY
        at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.exec.JDBCResultSetImpl.nextRow(JDBCResultSetImpl.java:179)
        at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.struct.JDBCTable.readData(JDBCTable.java:195)
        at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.controls.resultset.ResultSetJobDataRead.lambda$0(ResultSetJobDataRead.java:110)
        at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.exec.DBExecUtils.tryExecuteRecover(DBExecUtils.java:164)
        at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.controls.resultset.ResultSetJobDataRead.run(ResultSetJobDataRead.java:108)
        at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.controls.resultset.ResultSetViewer$17.run(ResultSetViewer.java:3468)
        at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.runtime.AbstractJob.run(AbstractJob.java:103)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Query failed (#20200212_074009_00007_z9eqz): The column event_timestamp is declared as type timestamp, but the Parquet file declares the column as type BINARY
        at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoResultSet.resultsException(PrestoResultSet.java:1840)
        at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoResultSet$ResultsPageIterator.computeNext(PrestoResultSet.java:1820)
        at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoResultSet$ResultsPageIterator.computeNext(PrestoResultSet.java:1759)
        at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.internal.guava.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:141)
        at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.internal.guava.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:136)
        at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.internal.guava.collect.TransformedIterator.hasNext(TransformedIterator.java:42)
        at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.internal.guava.collect.Iterators$ConcatenatedIterator.getTopMetaIterator(Iterators.java:1311)
        at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.internal.guava.collect.Iterators$ConcatenatedIterator.hasNext(Iterators.java:1327)
        at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.LengthLimitedIterator.hasNext(LengthLimitedIterator.java:42)
        at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoResultSet.next(PrestoResultSet.java:144)
        at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.exec.JDBCResultSetImpl.next(JDBCResultSetImpl.java:268)
        at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.exec.JDBCResultSetImpl.nextRow(JDBCResultSetImpl.java:176)
        ... 7 more
    Caused by: com.facebook.presto.spi.PrestoException: The column event_timestamp is declared as type timestamp, but the Parquet file declares the column as type BINARY
        at com.facebook.presto.hive.parquet.ParquetPageSourceFactory.getParquetType(ParquetPageSourceFactory.java:301)
        at com.facebook.presto.hive.parquet.ParquetPageSourceFactory.getColumnType(ParquetPageSourceFactory.java:404)
        at com.facebook.presto.hive.parquet.ParquetPageSourceFactory.lambda$createParquetPageSource$1(ParquetPageSourceFactory.java:185)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
        at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1382)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
        at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.reduce(ReferencePipeline.java:546)
        at com.facebook.presto.hive.parquet.ParquetPageSourceFactory.createParquetPageSource(ParquetPageSourceFactory.java:189)
        at com.facebook.presto.hive.parquet.ParquetPageSourceFactory.createPageSource(ParquetPageSourceFactory.java:139)
        at com.facebook.presto.hive.HivePageSourceProvider.createHivePageSource(HivePageSourceProvider.java:273)
        at com.facebook.presto.hive.HivePageSourceProvider.createPageSource(HivePageSourceProvider.java:120)
        at com.facebook.presto.spi.connector.classloader.ClassLoaderSafeConnectorPageSourceProvider.createPageSource(ClassLoaderSafeConnectorPageSourceProvider.java:51)
        at com.facebook.presto.split.PageSourceManager.createPageSource(PageSourceManager.java:58)
        at com.facebook.presto.operator.TableScanOperator.getOutput(TableScanOperator.java:248)
        at com.facebook.presto.operator.Driver.processInternal(Driver.java:379)
        at com.facebook.presto.operator.Driver.lambda$processFor$8(Driver.java:283)
        at com.facebook.presto.operator.Driver.tryWithLock(Driver.java:675)
        at com.facebook.presto.operator.Driver.processFor(Driver.java:276)
        at com.facebook.presto.execution.SqlTaskExecution$DriverSplitRunner.processFor(SqlTaskExecution.java:1077)
        at com.facebook.presto.execution.executor.PrioritizedSplitRunner.process(PrioritizedSplitRunner.java:162)
        at com.facebook.presto.execution.executor.TaskExecutor$TaskRunner.run(TaskExecutor.java:483)
        at com.facebook.presto.$gen.Presto_0_228_bcf44e4____20200212_073601_1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

(Since stackoverflow does not allow me to send this because of it's mostly code. i need to add some `lorem ipsum` statements)

Ut turpis purus, vulputate vitae semper vitae, convallis ut arcu. Etiam mattis mollis turpis sed vestibulum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1- Reason**

Presto fails when parquet's column order does not match the create statement order. Also this error sometime happens when parquet file does not contain some columns in the table.

**2- Solution**

Add following option to `hive.properties` file & restart the Presto :

```
hive.parquet.use-column-names=true
```

See also [Presto issue to turn `use-column-names` by default](https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues/1558).

Hope, it's help someone in the future!